# How to get a group of the highest Foo's in a SQL table

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table, that contains a column named `Foo`.

I know how to get a row with the highest Foo value, with some SQL like this:

```
SELECT MAX(Foo) AS HighestFoo FROM Foos;
```

How can I get all the rows with the highest Foo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Foos
WHERE
    Foo = (SELECT MAX(Foo) AS HighestFoo FROM Foos)
```

The subquery (on the last line) selects out the highest value, and then uses that value to modify the WHERE clause.

Comment: Just for the record, i also gave you +1, if you are wondering why you are on 0 votes atm. someone else most have giving you a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach (for those db's that support it) is to use dense_rank() over()

```
SELECT
      *
FROM (
            SELECT
                  *
                , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY FOO DESC) AS rnk
            FROM tblFoo
      ) AS sq
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With CTE As (
SELECT MAX(Foo) AS HighestFoo
       FROM Foos
)
Select * From Foos Where Foo = ( Select HighestFoo From CTE)
```

Comment: Gets the result! @Victor

Comment: This is not a explanation. You should explain why you've chosen this way!

Comment: there is no advantage in use of CTE here, it's the same as a direct subquery, all you have achieved is referencing the subquery via an alias